# Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode() makes assembly's namespace "disappear"?

Tags: c#, url, namespaces, encode

I have 2 C# projects (let's call them A and B). Project A is compiled to Class library and project B is compiled to Windows Application. Project B is added a reference to project A. Normally, they run well, without any problem.

I added a line that use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() to project A:

> ```
> string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryString);
> ```

and I also added 'using System.Web' and a reference to System.Web.dll. While project A still be built successfully, when I build project B, it gave me errors said that the namespace of project A does not exist. Removing the line that use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() solve the problem, but I really need that method.

Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've found the problem: I set the "target framework" property of project B as ".net framework 4 client profile", which seems not support System.Web. Just change it to ".net framework 4" and it works fine.

Comment: Do both projects contain the reference to System.Web.dll?

Comment: I am sure its got nothing to do with this. Check all references properly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more helpful to post the actual error message received with all its quirks for more assistance to be given.